# Sound generating with an AVR

Tags: avr, atmega, speakers

I'm just wondering how can I drive a speaker with an AVR chip, like Atmega16?

I have a source code for it and I have ran it in Proteus and it worked but I don't know how can I connect it practically. Should I use transistors or not?

How I should bias the transistor any way?

Is there something with my speaker maybe it's power is upper than the chip's power?
(I have a 2W speaker)

Comment: Try searching around here on stack exchange. Use key words such as "speaker",  "arduino",   here is one link : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66521/circuit-to-drive-a-speaker

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are almost just using headphones, you will not be able to drive anything from the pin on the micro controller. You will want an amplifier of some sort. Are you using PWM to create the sound? If so you can just use a single transistor and pullup resistor (First Circuit). Otherwise you really want a push pull style amplifier (Second Circuit) and you will need some biasing and more DC blocking. I would recommend searching a bit a bout amplifiers in that case. Also you really want a capacitor in series with the speaker to remove any DC current that would flow. This is critically important for the Single transistor model.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL9kYe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NOTE: These schematics are just examples, the values and transistors used may or may not be appropriate for your setup.

Comment: u know i use these codes for applying speaker . i just changed the frequency of special port to generating kinds of sound here is the codes:

Comment: while (1)
      {
      soundplayer(400,440);
      delay_ms(500);
     soundplayer(400,392);
      delay_ms(500);
      }
}
void soundplayer(float duration,float frequency)
{
 long int i,cycle;
 float wavetime;
 float nimwavetime;
 wavetime=((1./frequency)*1000);
 nimwavetime=wavetime/2;
 cycle=(1.*duration)/wavetime;
 for(i=0;i<cycle;i++)
 {
 delay_ms(nimwavetime);
 PORTD.0=1;
 delay_ms(nimwavetime);
 PORTD.0=0;
  }        these codes r using PWM? as i said i just change the frequency   thank u for reply i'll try what u said hope it works

Comment: @Samanshahsiah The code you posted must use some library because that is not gcc C or Arduino code. I'm assuming it is PWM because a basic Atmega16 or similar has no other way to make noise. If you have an N Type FET or NPN transistor you can try creating the first circuit above.

Comment: these r last lines of my codes i copied he bottom of them.please just tell me how i bias the transistor?i have pnp type of transistor is it works?

Comment: @Samanshahsiah You need to do some more research into this. Google amplifiers or search this site for the answers you seek.

Comment: @MadHatter, is the push-pull circuit correct? I think your transistors are swapped. With a 1v supply, I guess they won't go kablam, but with a bigger supply voltage, they'll both conduct.

Comment: @CarlRaymond you may be correct, as i noted below the images, the values may not be correct. I have now invested the time so it is more correct for anyone using it as a reference.